# install_python() raises Error in setwd(root) : cannot change working directory

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I was following the code at https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/install/. Then I encountered the following error that stopped me from continue.

```
> library(reticulate)
> path_to_python <- install_python()
Error in setwd(root) : cannot change working directory
```

Here is my `sessionInfo()`.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/Chicago
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] reticulate_1.28

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.0 Matrix_1.5-4   tools_4.3.0    rappdirs_0.3.3
[5] Rcpp_1.0.10    grid_4.3.0     jsonlite_1.8.4 png_0.1-8     
[9] lattice_0.21-8
```

How can I fix it and move on? Thanks.

---

Update on April 23:

The question was posted on https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow.rstudio.com/issues/56.

Comment: I edited the tags and title to reflect that this is a python/reticulate issue, not a TensorFlow one.

Comment: @dww … and I went ahead and removed the tags from the title ;-)